# Difference in browsers detecting extension type C#

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, contenttype

Currently using a file.contentType validation method to verify the extension type of an image uploaded to my application. Issue however if I download a .jpg image from the internet and rename it with a .png extension then try to upload it using my application, IE is detecting that it is not really a .png and rejects it. Chrome on the other hand uploads and displays it correctly.

I would like to know what is causing IE to notice this extension change and Chrome not to. Or does Chrome notice and just not care? I would either need to make IE accept the changed .jpeg --> .png OR, have Chrome pull the same error.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Sounds like a pure IE issue, which considers the dying of IE, would be less an issue in the future.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Or are you referring simply to the use of the HTML `<File>` element?

Comment: remove the c# tag or show that it is the serverside user agent logic causing the problem. "reject" > how? anyway, iinteresting find.

Comment: if youre returning a file action result you should consider having a mime type method that will give you the string for mime type and then you shouldnt have any issues

Comment: Thank you all for the input, I did have the mime type in there and it wasnt catching it. I switched to a `ImageFormat` from `System.Drawing.Imaging` to figure it out. Google Chrome now detects that it is in fact not actually a .png file.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to this post I found while doing some research.

http://www.aaronstannard.com/how-to-securely-verify-and-validate-image-uploads-in-aspnet-and-aspnet-mvc/